# How to disable automated sales order email notification to customer?

Tags: odoo

When I confirm a sale order an email is sent to my customer :

" You have been invited to follow SO014. Access your messages and personal documents through our Customer Portal".

I want to disable that action. When I access to basic sale workflow, there is no action server defined when a sale order is confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find the server actions `Setting -> Actions -> Server Actions`

Then find `Sale Orders` and remove the action there.

Comment: On the menu **server action**, i did not find any action related to **sale order**.

Comment: What did you find in server actions ? paste it

Comment: Currently trying to disable this myself. I found sale.order under the email settings but the mails are still sent to our customers.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to inherit the sale.order function action_confirm and remove all linked partners (and users) from the message_follower_ids.

```
@api.multi
    def action_confirm(self):

        return_value = super(sale_order, self.with_context(mail_create_nosubscribe=True)).action_confirm()

        for follower in self['message_follower_ids']:
            follower.unlink()

        return return_value
```